# Matching negative number range -20 to 19

Tags: bash

I was curious of how to match a negative number, specifically being -20 up to 19. I'm fairly new to bash and have never attempted a negative number before.

Comment: Are you assuming that a regular expression is the best solution? It isn't. You *can* match a range of numbers using a regular expression, but a small change in the range can require a major redesign of the regular expression.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1171/

Answer (score 3):

Using arithmetic (seems the better approach):

```
NUM="-20"

if [[ $NUM -gt -21 && $NUM -lt 20 ]];
then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "FAIL"
fi
```

Otherwise if you really want to use regex:

```
NUM="20"

if [[ $NUM =~ ^(-(20|1[0-9]|[1-9])|1?[0-9])$ ]];
then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "FAIL"
fi
```

Comment: I think using arithmetic is a better approach

Comment: You can also use (( )) for a more "traditional" look: `(( $NUM >= -20 && $NUM <= 19 ))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression :

```
(-(20|1[0-9]|[1-9])|1?[0-9])
```